# Counting years in y/m/d format in laravel

Tags: laravel, date

I have these as a sample of records
2016/01/13, 2016/01/15, 2016/01/25, 2015/01/14, 2015/01/17, 2015/01/28 and so on.

Any suggestions on how to only count (yyyy) where the month of January appears so that I get 2.(2016,2015)

```
$stocks = DB::table('inventories')

        ->select('inventories.*',DB::raw('count(*) as count,date_sold'))
        ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
        ->groupBy('inventories.drug_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Replace `->get()` with `->count()` and it will perform the count on the SQL level :). Or you can just chain them: `->get()->count()` and let php count the results.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

If you only need the count number and not the records from the database do this:

```
$stocks = DB::table('inventories')
    ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
    ->groupBy('inventories.drug_id')
    ->count();
```

This way $stock will equal to number of records found (example: `2`). The count will be performed on SQL level (example: `SELECT count(*) ....`).

**Option 2:**

If you will need the records later on, you could do it like this:

```
$stocks = DB::table('inventories')
    ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
    ->groupBy('inventories.drug_id')
    ->get();

$stockCount = $stock->count();
```

This way `$stock` will have the results of the query saved (the records from the database). And `$stockCount` will be a number of records. The count will be performed [on collection (php)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count).

Comment: I want both but from my question I want the result to be 2 and not 6... I only want to count the years 2016 and 2015 not all the records

Comment: @Ashley then add another where clause like this: `->whereYear('complete_sold', '>', '2014')`

Comment: Or actually if you want specifically for 2015 and 2016 you should do this: `->whereYear('complete_sold', '>', '2014')->whereYear('complete_sold', '<', '2017')`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** If you only want count

```
$stocks = DB::table('inventories')
    ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
    ->distinct()->count("year(complete_sold)");
```

**Option 2**: If you need the records of the years

```
$stocks = DB::table('inventories')
    ->whereMonth('complete_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
    ->select(DB::raw("year(complete_sold)"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(complete_sold)"))->get();
```